# error when running a Flutter app on my device in Android Studio : "ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have this error when I try to lunch my Flutter project, can someone explain it please or give a possible solution ?

```
ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

  Command: C:\Users\asmou\AndroidStudioProjects\pubrech\android\gradlew.bat -q -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64 -Ptarget=C:\Users\asmou\AndroidStudioProjects\pubrech\lib\main.dart -Pdart-defines=Zmx1dHRlci5pbnNwZWN0b3Iuc3RydWN0dXJlZEVycm9ycz10cnVl,RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQVVUT19ERVRFQ1Q9dHJ1ZQ== -Pdart-obfuscation=false -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=false -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by simply creating a new project and moved project files to new project , looks like something was corrupted

Answer (score 1):

Your gradlew wrapper executable is probably broken:

Rebuild wrapper:

```
cd MyProject\android
MyProject\android> C:\Users\MyUSername\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.x-bin\f1w0cc9nuo0eivz97x2xlu9sv\gradle-7.x\bin\gradle wrapper
```

or short: `MyProject\android> gradle wrapper`, if you have installed gradle globally.

Do a clean build

```
MyProject\android> gradlew clean build
```

Run you flutter app.